# Catalog Price Rule Not Working On Live Site

Tags: magento-1.9, error, catalog-price-rules, default

Catalog price rule not working on my live site, may i know the possibilities of error? Is necessary for cron job?

Workout:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i solve the issue?

Comment: My Magento version : 1.9.2.3

Comment: have you did reindex?

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati Yes i did that.

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati may i know the possibilities or error?

Comment: Are checking that in australian website or main website ?

Comment: Yes, i have multi-store, i need to apply for this my Australian site

Answer (score 0):

Catalog price rules have to be applied.
First of all: do that and clear the full page cache. 
If they show up again your cronjob has a problem and you need to investigate further.
Mayve your timezone is off so you'd remove the filtering. 
If they don't your testing or configuration is wrong or your price template is overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do following things:

- Try to save and apply rule from rule page and also rules grid.
- Try by changing "is one of" to "contains" in actions.
- If you have multiple rule enabled then Also check "applied_rule_ids" in sales_flat_quote table that is any other rule applying or not?

I hope this will help you.

Comment: My Id : https://snag.gy/evTf7z.jpg, and it is not available in sales_flat_quote

Comment: Okay..Have you tried other options?

Comment: Yes,  i did remaining steps.

Comment: Still not apply discount on website

Comment: Anything else i need to update?

Comment: Try with enable discount on subproduct in action tab

Comment: I done with shopping cart price rule, but the discount applied on subtotal how can i set condition like discount apply only on discounted product not subtotal